# How to create a search bar with multiple filters in Wechat applet

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I need to create a search bar with keyword filters, as shown in the image below.

[Search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKVTF.png)

How will this be achieved? Is there any component for this?

Can we use jquery in wechat mini?

Answer (score 0):

In wechat miniprogram running environment,no "window" object.So jquery will not work.But you could use “SelectorQuery” APIs.It's similiar as JQ.

docs:https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/api/wxml/SelectorQuery.html

To contral the views, you need to learn to contral data to change views instead of contral the view nodes directly.You can create a miniprogram demo to kwon this.